# Mean of log of $X$ with normal distribution: $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \log(| \alpha x + \beta |) \frac{ 1}{\sqrt{2\pi} }e^{\frac{-x^2}{2} }{\rm d}x$

Tags: probability, integration

The expectation of the log of the absolute value of random variable with the standard normal distrbution can be computed based on the result provided here [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1921046/1231520).

How can this be computed for an arbitrary normal distrbution. It is equivalent to finding the following expectation:

$$\mathbb E [\log|\alpha X + \beta|]=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}
\log(| \alpha x + \beta |) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{2} }{\rm d}x $$

where $X$ has the standard normal distribution.

For $\beta=0$, the formula is

$$\mathbb E [\log|\alpha X|]=\log|\alpha|-\frac{1}{2}  (\gamma +\log (2))$$

where $\gamma$ denotes the Euler's constant.

Comment: If we were to drop the absolute value from the logarithm then the result, along with various generalizations, is given here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1359584/an-integral-involving-a-gaussian-and-a-logarithm .

Comment: What is your motivation for asking that question? Is it a pure mathematical curiosity or does it have real life applications?

Comment: @Przemo I think it is a good measure for comparing the magnitude of different distributions; it is even finite for the Cauchy distribution: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4838543/1231520. 

You may also see the background discussed here for another application: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4843188/1231520. Note that $$\mathbb E \left( \log(|1-\alpha X^2|) \right )=\mathbb E \bigg [ \log(|1-\sqrt{\alpha}X|)+\log(|1+\sqrt{\alpha}X|) \bigg ]. $$

Comment: @Przemo Regarding your first comment above, after dropping the absolute value, the log cannot be used for negative values. How did you manage this?

Comment: Of course it can be. $\log (x) = \log(\left| x \right|) + \imath arg(x)$.

Comment: @Przemo Nice! Now I see; you used the complex logarithm, and the real part of the formula provided in your question above (for the normal distribution) is equal to the solution here for $\beta=1$ and $\alpha=A$ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Notations

- $\displaystyle F(z):=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}e^{-z^2}\text{erfi}(z)\text{ is the Dawson integral}$
- $\gamma$ is the Eulero-Mascheroni constant
- ${}_pF_q(a_1,...,a_p; b_1,...,b_q|z)$ is the hypergemetric function
- P.V. is the principal value

---

You can use again the Feymann trick, but now it's more complex:
$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\left|ax+b\right|\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx=&\frac{\ln\left(\left|a\right|\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\left|x+\frac{b}{a}\right|\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx\\
=&\ln\left(\left|a\right|\right)+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\left|x+\frac{b}{a}\right|\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx\end{align}$$

Let
$$G\left(s\right):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\left|x+s\right|\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx$$
$$g\left(s\right):=G'(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\text{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}}{x+s}dx=\sqrt{2}F\left(\frac{s}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

So
$$G(s)=\frac{s^2}{2}{}_2F_2\left(\left.{1,1\atop\frac{3}{2},2}\right|-\frac{s^2}{2}\right)+c_0$$
$c_0$ is a constant and is determined by imposing the passage for $0$:
$$c_0=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\left|x\right|\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx=-\frac{\ln\left(2\right)+\gamma}{2}$$

So

$$\color{blue}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\left|ax+b\right|\right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}dx=\ln(|a|)+\frac{b^2}{2a^2}\cdot{}_2F_2\left(\left.{1,1\atop\frac{3}{2},2}\right|-\frac{b^2}{2a^2}\right)-\frac{\ln\left(2\right)+\gamma}{2}}$$

---

> P.S.: To check the correctness of my formula I leave you two Wolfram links: in the first the one with [the integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate%20from%20-infty%20to%20infty%20ln%28%7C6.2%20x-2.3%7C%29%2Fsqrt%282%20pi%29%20e%5E%28-x%5E2%2F2%29), in the second the one with the [solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ln%28%7Ca%7C%29%2Bb%5E2%2F%282a%5E2%29*HypergeometricPFQ%28%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B3%2F2%2C2%7D%2C-b%5E2%2F%282a%5E2%29%29-%28ln%282%29%2BEulerGamma%29%2F2%20where%20a%3D6.2%2C%20b%3D-2.3) (you can change the command and put random values, in this case I put $a=6.2$ and $b=- 2.3$)

---

### Update

In answer to the question if the hypergeometric function can be simplied the answer is no. At most I can give you a numerical method to calculate it yourself:

$${}_2F_2\left(\left.{1,1\atop\frac{3}{2},2}\right|-\frac{z^2}{2}\right)=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-1\right)^{n}\frac{2^{n}n!}{\left(2n+2\right)!}z^{2n}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer and links! Can the second term be simplified future?

Comment: @Amir I updated the answer

Comment: Thank you for your kind support!